# Operaciones con select y span con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estimados necesito su ayuda, como podría realizar operaciones con :

`<span>` y `<select> <option>`
con `javascript` Mi código.

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>cantidad Habitacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Matrimonial</td>
      <td><span id="precio_1">200.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_1" name="reserva_1">
          <option id="matrimonial_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="matrimonial_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="matrimonial_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Simple</td>
      <td><span id="precio_2">120.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_2" name="reserva_2">
          <option id="simple_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="simple_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="simple_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="simple_3" value="3">3-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Doble</td>
      <td><span id="precio_3">200.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_3" name="reserva_3">
          <option id="doble_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="doble_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="doble_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="doble_3" value="3">3-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="doble_4" value="4">4-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="calcular" name="button">Calcular</button> Total de reservas : <input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" disabled="" value="">
```

Esta `tabla` es dinámica, el `javascript` tiene que poder realizar las operaciones,cuando haya solo un tipo de habitación o mas, las filas no son estáticas, (en mi bucle en php pongo un id diferente  en las etiquetas `span` y `select` y sus `option` respectivos, con eso deseo trabajar las operaciones) 
Como debe de calcular

el `option` se multiplica con `span` (por fila)
y al final realizaría la sumatoria.

mejor dicho `precio` * `cantidad habitacion` y su total. 
Poniendo el resultado en el `input id='resultado'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
// seleccionamos todos los select cuyo id empieze con la palabra reserva
var sele = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^="reserva"]');
// seleccionamos el id resultado del input 
var res = document.querySelector("#resultado");
//creamos un arreglo vacio
var total = [];

//interamos por cada select que este en el documento
for(var i=0 ; i < sele.length; i++){
// rellenamos las posiciones de total con base a la cantidad de select
// y le asignamos 0 como valor inicial a todos
total[i]=0;
// agregamos un evento change por cada select del documento
sele[i].addEventListener("change", (e)=>{

// creamos un variable llamada el que guardara el select seleccionado xD
let el = e.target;
// creamos un variable ids que almacenara la numeracion del id con una 
// expresion regular solo nos extrae el numero 1 2 u 3 a eso 
// le restamos -1 porque las posiciones de un arreglo son desde 0
   let ids= el.id.match(/\d+/)[0]-1;
// del select buscamos su padre que seria td
   // luego el padre de td que seria tr
   // de ahi buscamos el td que contega un span que contenga un id que empieze
   //  con la palabra precio y obtenemos el texto
   let price = el.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('td span[id^="precio"]').textContent;
// asignamos a total en la posicio ids el valor de options
// lo multiplicamos por el precio
total[ids] =  ( el.value*price );
// sumamos todos los valores del arreglo total
sum = total.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
// cambiamos el attributo value por el valor de la suma
// le decimos que queremos 2 decimales con toFixed();
res.setAttribute("value",sum.toFixed(2));

  });
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categoria</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>cantidad Habitacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Matrimonial</td>
      <td><span id="precio_1">200.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_1" name="reserva_1">
          <option id="matrimonial_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="matrimonial_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="matrimonial_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Simple</td>
      <td><span id="precio_2">120.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_2" name="reserva_2">
          <option id="simple_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="simple_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="simple_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="simple_3" value="3">3-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Doble</td>
      <td><span id="precio_3">200.00</span></td>
      <td>
        <select id="reserva_3" name="reserva_3">
          <option id="doble_0" value="0">0</option>
          <option id="doble_1" value="1">1-habitacion</option>
          <option id="doble_2" value="2">2-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="doble_3" value="3">3-habitaciones</option>
          <option id="doble_4" value="4">4-habitaciones</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="calcular" name="button">Calcular</button> Total de reservas : <input type="text" name="resultado" id="resultado" disabled="" value="0.00">
```

Comment: Tu código esta muy bien pero intenta desarrollarlo un poco. Explicar como funciona ese JS y que hace. Puede que la persona que pregunta o los próximos usuarios no entiendan como aplicarlo.